# Criar menu de um arquivo JSON usando AngularJS

Tags: javascript, json, twitter-bootstrap, angularjs

Tenho um arquivo JSON com a seguinte extrutura:

```
"[{\"Menu\":\"General/Register/User\"},
{\"Menu\":\"App/MultiExport/Parameter\"},
{\"Menu\":\"App/MultiExport/CreateFile\"},
{\"Menu\":\"App/MultiCube/Create\"}]"
```

Como faço para criar um menu usando **AngularJS** a partir desse JSON?

Vale destacar que, cada "/" é um nível de submenu:

```
.General
      .Register
              .User
.App
      .MultiExport
              .Parameter
              .Create File
      .MultiCube
              .Create
```

Comment: Vão ser somente 3 níveis ou vão ter mais?

Comment: Então, este JSON está retornando de um webservice... Por enquanto temos 3 níveis mas podem surgir novos níveis.

Comment: Essa estrutura do JSON pode ser alterada?

Answer (score 0):

Opa Lucas,

Primeiro converte para um json, pois o angular está pensando que é uma String e está colocando essas barras.

```
var novoJSON = angular.fromJson(objetoDoJson);
```

assim você pode brincar com o objeto e criar a lista que deseja.

O objeto Javascript irá ficar assim:

```
[{Menu:"General/Register/User"},
{Menu:"App/MultiExport/Parameter"},
{Menu:"App/MultiExport/CreateFile"},
{Menu:"App/MultiCube/Create"}]
```